# ISDone (error) finish page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am having a problem with ISdone library error finish page.
according to the library error page should be in red colour like this:[image]

But i am not getting the red colour:[image]

I know why this is happening,This is because of the code of stratching the image.
Now how can i get the red colour for `FinishedLabel` and `FinishedHeadingLabel` if ISDone error occures.

*Thank You* **.**

***Script :***

```
; --- Generated by InnoSetup Script Joiner version 3.0, Jul 22 2009, (c) Bulat Ziganshin <Bulat.Ziganshin@gmail.com>. More info at http://issjoiner.codeplex.com/

; --- Source: 2.iss ------------------------------------------------------------
// Setup.ini internal

#define MyAppName "Game"
#define MyAppVersion "2.0.0.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Dante1995"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"
#define NeedSize "5000000"
// only Arc, Disable PrecompInside
;#Define PrecompInside  

[Setup]
WizardSmallImageFile=Include\WizModernSmallImage.bmp
WizardImageFile=Include\WizModernImage-IS.bmp
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVerName={#MyAppName}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
OutputDir=Output
Compression=zip
InternalCompressLevel=Ultra64
SetupIconFile=include\icon.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon={uninstallexe}
VersionInfoCopyright={#MyAppPublisher}
#ifdef NeedSize
ExtraDiskSpaceRequired={#NeedSize}
#endif

DisableWelcomePage=False
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes

[Languages]
Name: "default"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}";
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked;

Name: DX; Description: Install Microsoft DirectX
Name: VC; Description: Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redist

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Play {#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Check: CheckError
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Check: CheckError
Name: "{commondesktop}\Play {#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Check: CheckError; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Check: CheckError; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Files]

#ifdef PrecompInside
Source: include\facompress.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\CLS-precomp.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\packjpg_dll.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\packjpg_dll1.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\precomp.exe; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\zlib1.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
#endif
#ifdef SrepInside
Source: include\CLS-srep.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\cls.ini; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
#endif
#ifdef MSC
Source: include\CLS-MSC.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
#endif
Source: include\English.ini; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\unarc.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\ISDone.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: include\CallbackCtrl.dll; Flags: dontcopy noencryption noencryption
Source: include\arc.ini; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy

Source: "Setup.ini"; Flags: dontcopy solidbreak;

[CustomMessages]
default.ORE=h
default.MINUTI=min
default.SECONDI=sec
default.RIMANENTE=Remaining Time:
default.ESTRAZIONE=Extracted Files:
default.TTime=Total Extraction Time :
default.Elapsed=Elapsed Time:

[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}"
Type: dirifempty; Name: "{pf}\{#MyAppPublisher}"

[Messages]
default.SetupWindowTitle=%1

[Code]

var
ElapsedTimeLbl,TotalTimeLbl,Percentuale,//RollingBack,
RemainingTimeLbl,LabelCurrFileName: TLabel;
ISDoneCancel:integer;
ISDoneError:boolean;
CancelBtn: TButton;
PBOldProc     : Longint;
WFCaption     : string;
eTime, sTime  : DWORD;

type
#ifdef UNICODE
 PChar = PAnsiChar;
#endif
TCallback = function (OveralPct,CurrentPct: integer;CurrentFile,TimeStr1,TimeStr2,TimeStr3:PAnsiChar): longword;
TPBProc = function (h:hWnd;Msg,wParam,lParam:Longint):Longint;


function SetWindowLong(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; dwNewLong: Longint): Longint; external 'SetWindowLongA@user32.dll stdcall';
function CallBackProc(P:TPBProc;ParamCount:integer):LongWord; external 'wrapcallbackaddr@files:CallbackCtrl.dll stdcall';
function CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndFunc: Longint; hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam, lParam: Longint): Longint; external 'CallWindowProcA@user32.dll stdcall';
function GetTickCount: DWORD; external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function WrapCallback(callback:TCallback; paramcount:integer):longword;external 'wrapcallback@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISDoneInit(RecordFileName:AnsiString; TimeType,Comp1,Comp2,Comp3:Cardinal; WinHandle, NeededMem:longint; callback:TCallback):boolean; external 'ISDoneInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';
function ISArcExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutPath, ExtractedPath: AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean; Password, CfgFile, WorkPath: AnsiString; ExtractPCF: boolean ):boolean; external 'ISArcExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function IS7ZipExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutPath: AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean; Password: AnsiString):boolean; external 'IS7zipExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISRarExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutPath: AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean; Password: AnsiString):boolean; external 'ISRarExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISPrecompExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutFile: AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISPrecompExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISSRepExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutFile: AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISSrepExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISxDeltaExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; minRAM,maxRAM:integer; InName, DiffFile, OutFile: AnsiString; DeleteInFile, DeleteDiffFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISxDeltaExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISPackZIP(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutFile: AnsiString;ComprLvl:integer; DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISPackZIP@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ShowChangeDiskWindow(Text, DefaultPath, SearchFile:AnsiString):boolean; external 'ShowChangeDiskWindow@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function Exec2 (FileName, Param: PAnsiChar;Show:boolean):boolean; external 'Exec2@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISFindFiles(CurComponent:Cardinal; FileMask:AnsiString; var ColFiles:integer):integer; external 'ISFindFiles@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISPickFilename(FindHandle:integer; OutPath:AnsiString; var CurIndex:integer; DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISPickFilename@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISGetName(TypeStr:integer):PAnsichar; external 'ISGetName@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISFindFree(FindHandle:integer):boolean; external 'ISFindFree@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISExec(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal,SpecifiedProcessTime:double; ExeName,Parameters,TargetDir,OutputStr:AnsiString;Show:boolean):boolean; external 'ISExec@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function SrepInit(TmpPath:PAnsiChar;VirtMem,MaxSave:Cardinal):boolean; external 'SrepInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function PrecompInit(TmpPath:PAnsiChar;VirtMem:cardinal;PrecompVers:single):boolean; external 'PrecompInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function FileSearchInit(RecursiveSubDir:boolean):boolean; external 'FileSearchInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISDoneStop:boolean; external 'ISDoneStop@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';
function ChangeLanguage(Language:AnsiString):boolean; external 'ChangeLanguage@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function SuspendProc:boolean; external 'SuspendProc@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';
function ResumeProc:boolean; external 'ResumeProc@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';

function ProgressCallback(OveralPct,CurrentPct: integer;CurrentFile,TimeStr1,TimeStr2,TimeStr3:PAnsiChar): longword;
begin
if OveralPct<=Wizardform.ProgressGauge.Max then
Wizardform.Progressgauge.Position := OveralPct;
Result := ISDoneCancel;
TotalTimeLbl.Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:TTime}')+TimeStr2;
with WizardForm.ProgressGauge do begin
LabelCurrFileName.Caption:=SetupMessage(msgStatusExtractFiles)+': '+MinimizePathName(CurrentFile, LabelCurrFileName.Font, LabelCurrFileName.Width-ScaleX(100));
end;
end;

function LongintToStringTime(t:Longint):string;
var
h,m,s:integer;
begin
h:=t div 3600;
t:=t-h*3600;
m:=t div 60;
s:=t-m*60;
Result:='';
if h>0 then Result:=Result+IntToStr(h)+ ExpandConstant(' {cm:ORE} ');
if (m>0) or (h>0) then Result:=Result+IntToStr(m)+ExpandConstant(' {cm:MINUTI} ');
if (m>0) or (h>0) or (s>0) then Result:=Result+IntToStr(s)+ExpandConstant(' {cm:SECONDI} ');
end;

function PBProc(h:hWnd;Msg,wParam,lParam:Longint):Longint;
var
R,A:Longint;
dt,at,pr,i1,i2:Extended;
p:string;
tc:DWORD;
begin
Result:=CallWindowProc(PBOldProc,h,Msg,wParam,lParam);
if (Msg=$402) and (WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position>WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Min) then begin
i1:=WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position-WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Min;
i2:=WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max-WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Min;
tc:=GetTickCount;
if (tc-eTime)>=1000 then begin
dt:=(tc-sTime)/1000;
at:=i2*dt/i1;
R:=Round(at-dt)
A:=Round(dt)
RemainingTimeLbl.Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:RIMANENTE} ')+LongintToStringTime(R);
ElapsedTimeLbl.Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:Elapsed} ')+LongintToStringTime(A);
eTime:=tc;
end;
pr:=i1*100/i2;
p:=''+Format('%f',[pr])+'%';
StringChange(p,',','.');
Percentuale.Caption:=WFCaption+p;
end;
end;

procedure AllCancel;
begin
SetWindowLong(WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Handle,-4,PBOldProc);
Percentuale.Caption:=WFCaption;
end;

procedure CancelButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
SuspendProc;
//RollingBack.Show;
if MsgBox(SetupMessage(msgExitSetupMessage), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then ISDoneCancel:=1;
ResumeProc;
//RollingBack.Hide;
end;

procedure HideControls;
begin
CancelBtn.Hide;
LabelCurrFileName.Hide;
RemainingTimeLbl.Hide;
ElapsedTimeLbl.Hide;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard1();
begin

WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top := ScaleY(46);

ElapsedTimeLbl := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
with ElapsedTimeLbl do begin
Parent := WizardForm.InstallingPage;
Font.Size:=10;
Font.Color:=clYellow;
Font.Style := [fsBold];
Font.Name:='calibri';
SetBounds(0,90,WizardForm.ClientWidth-40,14);
end;

RemainingTimeLbl:=TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
with RemainingTimeLbl do begin
Parent:=WizardForm.InstallingPage;
SetBounds(216,90,WizardForm.ClientWidth-40,14);
Font.Size:=10;
Font.Color:=clYellow;
Font.Style := [fsBold];
Font.Name:='calibri';
end;

Percentuale := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
with Percentuale do begin
Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;
SetBounds(150,130,WizardForm.ClientWidth-40,14);
Font.Size:=20;
Font.Color:=clYellow;
Font.Style := [fsBold];
Font.Name:='calibri';
end;

CancelBtn := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
with CancelBtn do begin
Name := 'Cancel';
Parent := WizardForm;
Left := WizardForm.CancelButton.Left;
Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
Width := WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
OnClick:=@CancelButtonOnClick;
Font.Size:=8;
Font.Name:='calibri';
end;

LabelCurrFileName := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
with LabelCurrFileName do begin
Parent   := WizardForm.InstallingPage;
AutoSize := False;
Width    := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Width+ScaleX(30);
Left     := ScaleX(0);
Top      := ScaleY(30);
Font.Size:=8;
Font.Color:=clYellow;
Font.Name:='calibri';
end;

TotalTimeLbl := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
with TotalTimeLbl do begin
Parent   := WizardForm.FinishedPage;
AutoSize := False;
Width    := 300;
Left     := 180;
Top      := 200;
Font.Size:=14;
Font.Color:=clYellow;
Font.Style := [fsBold];
Font.Name:='calibri';
Height := 35;
end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged1(CurPageID: integer);
begin
HideControls;
if CurPageID=wpWelcome then
begin
end;
if CurPageID=wpSelectDir then
begin
end;

if CurPageID=wpInstalling then
begin
CancelBtn.Show;
LabelCurrFileName.Show;
RemainingTimeLbl.Show;
ElapsedTimeLbl.Show;
end;

if CurPageID=wpFinished then
begin
RemainingTimeLbl.Hide;
AllCancel;
HideControls;
end;

if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and ISDoneError then
begin
WizardForm.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgErrorTitle);
WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Font.Color:= clRed;
WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgSetupAborted);
end;
end;

function CheckError:boolean;
begin
result:= not ISDoneError;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged1(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
res, i, ResultCode: integer;
Arc1, Arc2: Array of String;
begin

If CurStep = ssInstall then begin
WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption:='Installing The Game...';

sTime:=GetTickCount;
eTime:=sTime;
PBOldProc:=SetWindowLong(WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Handle,-4,CallBackProc(@PBProc,4));

#ifdef PrecompInside
ExtractTemporaryFile('CLS-precomp.dll');
ExtractTemporaryFile('packjpg_dll.dll');
ExtractTemporaryFile('packjpg_dll1.dll');
ExtractTemporaryFile('precomp.exe');
ExtractTemporaryFile('zlib1.dll');
ExtractTemporaryFile('facompress.dll');
#endif
#ifdef SrepInside
ExtractTemporaryFile('CLS-srep.dll');
#endif
#ifdef MSC
ExtractTemporaryFile('CLS-MSC.dll');
#endif
ExtractTemporaryFile('arc.ini');
ExtractTemporaryFile('unarc.dll');
ExtractTemporaryFile('English.ini');

ISDoneError:=false;
i:=1;
if (GetIniString('FreearcFile' + IntToStr(i),'Archive','',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.ini')) <> '') then
begin
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max:=0;
repeat
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max:= WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max + 1000;
i:= i + 1;
until (GetIniString('FreearcFile' + IntToStr(i),'Archive','',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.ini')) = '');
end;
if ISDoneInit(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\records.inf'), $F777, 0,0,0, MainForm.Handle, 512, @ProgressCallback) then begin
repeat
ChangeLanguage('English');
if not SrepInit('',512,0) then ISDoneError := True;
if not PrecompInit('',128,0) then ISDoneError := True;
if not FileSearchInit(true) then ISDoneError := True;
i:=1;
if (GetIniString('FreearcFile' + IntToStr(i),'Archive','',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.ini')) <> '') then
begin
SetArrayLength(Arc1,4);
SetArrayLength(Arc2,4);
repeat
Arc1[0]:=ExpandConstant(GetIniString('FreearcFile' + IntToStr(i),'Archive','',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.ini')));
Arc1[1]:=ExpandConstant(GetIniString('FreearcFile' + IntToStr(i),'Output','',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.ini')));
Arc1[2]:=ExpandConstant(GetIniString('FreearcFile' + IntToStr(i),'Disk','1',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.ini')));
if Arc1[0] <> '' then
begin
if not FileExists(Arc1[0]) then
begin
if MsgBox(SetupMessage(msgChangeDiskTitle) +'  '+'( '+ Arc1[2]+' )', mbError, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDCANCEL then ISDoneError := True;
end else begin
if not ISArcExtract( 0, 0, Arc1[0], Arc1[1], '', false, Arc1[3], ExpandConstant('{tmp}\arc.ini'), ExpandConstant('{app}'), False) then ISDoneError := True;
i:= i + 1;
end;
end;
until ((GetIniString('FreearcFile' + IntToStr(i),'Archive','',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.ini')) = '') or (ISDoneError = True));
end;
until true;
ISDoneStop;
end;
AllCancel;
HideControls;
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Hide;
end;
if (CurStep=ssPostInstall) and ISDoneError then begin
WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption:=SetupMessage(msgStatusRollback);
TotalTimeLbl.Caption:='';
Exec(ExpandConstant('{uninstallexe}'), '/VERYSILENT','', sw_Hide, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
end;

function InitializeSetup1: Boolean;

var
Uninstall,Location: string;
ResultCode: Integer;
begin
if not FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\CallbackCtrl.dll')) then ExtractTemporaryFile('CallbackCtrl.dll');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Setup.ini');
if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppName}_is1','UninstallString', Uninstall) then
Uninstall:=RemoveQuotes(Uninstall);
begin
if not Exec(Uninstall, ' /SILENT', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppName}_is1','InstallLocation', Location);
end;
Result:=True;
end;








[Setup]


; --- Source: 3.iss ------------------------------------------------------------

[code]
var
  WelcomeLabel1, WelcomeLabel2, FinishedLabel, FinishedHeadingLabel: TLabel;
  PageNameLabel, PageDescriptionLabel: TLabel;

procedure InitializeWizard2();
begin
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Width := ScaleX(497);
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Width := ScaleX(497);

  { WelcomeLabel1 }
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Hide;
  WelcomeLabel1 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1 do
  begin
    WelcomeLabel1.Parent := Parent;
    WelcomeLabel1.SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
    WelcomeLabel1.AutoSize := AutoSize;
    WelcomeLabel1.Font := Font;
    WelcomeLabel1.Font.Color := clWhite;
    WelcomeLabel1.Transparent := True;
    WelcomeLabel1.WordWrap := WordWrap;
    WelcomeLabel1.Caption := Caption;
  end;

  { WelcomeLabel2 }
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Hide;
  WelcomeLabel2 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2 do
  begin
    WelcomeLabel2.Parent := Parent;
    WelcomeLabel2.SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
    WelcomeLabel2.AutoSize := AutoSize;
    WelcomeLabel2.Font := Font;
    WelcomeLabel2.Font.Color := clWhite;
    WelcomeLabel2.Transparent := True;
    WelcomeLabel2.WordWrap := WordWrap;
    WelcomeLabel2.Caption := Caption;
  end;

  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.SetBounds(ScaleX(0), ScaleY(0), WizardForm.MainPanel.Width, WizardForm.MainPanel.Height);

  { PageNameLabel }
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Hide;
  PageNameLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with WizardForm.PageNameLabel do
  begin
    PageNameLabel.Parent := Parent;
    PageNameLabel.SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
    PageNameLabel.AutoSize := AutoSize;
    PageNameLabel.Font := Font;
    PageNameLabel.Font.Color := clYellow;
    PageNameLabel.Transparent := True;
    PageNameLabel.WordWrap := WordWrap;
  end;

  { PageDescriptionLabel }
  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Hide;
  PageDescriptionLabel:= TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel do
  begin
    PageDescriptionLabel.Parent := Parent;
    PageDescriptionLabel.SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
    PageDescriptionLabel.AutoSize := AutoSize;
    PageDescriptionLabel.Font := Font;
    PageDescriptionLabel.Font.Color := clYellow;
    PageDescriptionLabel.Transparent := True;
    PageDescriptionLabel.WordWrap := WordWrap;
  end;

  { FinishedHeadingLabel }
  WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Hide;
  FinishedHeadingLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel do
  begin
    FinishedHeadingLabel.Parent := Parent;
    FinishedHeadingLabel.SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
    FinishedHeadingLabel.AutoSize := AutoSize;
    FinishedHeadingLabel.Font := Font;
    FinishedHeadingLabel.Font.Color := clWhite;
    FinishedHeadingLabel.Transparent := True;
    FinishedHeadingLabel.WordWrap := WordWrap;
    FinishedHeadingLabel.Caption := Caption;
  end;

  { FinishedLabel }
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Hide;
  FinishedLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with WizardForm.FinishedLabel do
  begin
    FinishedLabel.Parent := Parent;
    FinishedLabel.SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
    FinishedLabel.AutoSize := AutoSize;
    FinishedLabel.Font := Font;
    FinishedLabel.Font.Color := clWhite;
    FinishedLabel.Transparent := True;
    FinishedLabel.WordWrap := WordWrap;
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged2(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  begin
    PageNameLabel.Caption := WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption;
    PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;
    FinishedLabel.Caption := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption;
  end;
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and ISDoneError then
  begin
  WizardForm.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgErrorTitle);
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Font.Color:= clRed;
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgSetupAborted);
  end;
end;
[Setup]


; --- Dispatching code ------------------------------------------------------------

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  InitializeWizard1();
  InitializeWizard2();
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  CurPageChanged1(CurPageID);
  CurPageChanged2(CurPageID);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  CurStepChanged1(CurStep);
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := InitializeSetup1(); if not Result then exit;
end;
```

Comment: anyone please Response.

Comment: This looks like another suspicious blackboxed DLL library. Are its sources available? Also the first line says you are using some tool from 2009, that is really old. Nobody can assure such old/unknown code will help.

Comment: Do u even know what blackbox library is?

Comment: And no this is not blackbox library  it is ISDone library. Do check atleast once.

Comment: The tool maybe old but is efficient and has no bug(Didn't notice any). And the tool is not for writing code  it's for merging 2 individual script.

Answer (score 0):

You'r Label's are messed up. If you are creating a new label in the place of an existing one make sure you use it everywhere. Dont mix it up!

Though i would not proceed with a code such as that in its current state...here's a fix.

Set the parent of **FinishedLabel** to WizardForm.FinishedPage

```
with WizardForm.FinishedLabel do begin
    FinishedLabel.Parent:=WizardForm.FinishedPage;
    ....
end;
```

and use that FinishedLabel to display the error message.

```
if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and ISDoneError then
begin
    WizardForm.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgErrorTitle);
    FinishedLabel.Font.Color:= clRed;
    WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgSetupAborted);
end;
```

in procedure CurPageChanged2.

Btw the code is very clumsy. Please take some time to go through your code and organise it before you go any further.

**Edit**: The updated code. I have tested this code in my PC and its working fine. Replace the CurPageChanged2 with this.

```
procedure CurPageChanged2(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  begin
    PageNameLabel.Caption := WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption;
    PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;
    FinishedLabel.Caption := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption;
  end;
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and ISDoneError then
  begin
  WizardForm.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgErrorTitle);
  FinishedLabel.Font.Color:= clRed; // changed
  FinishedHeadingLabel.Font.Color:= clRed; // changed
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgSetupAborted);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure you made the correct changes?. I have tested it and it works fine on my PC. Post the updated code somewhere so that i can check it.

Comment: check the code (question) again i already have the same code u stated above.

Comment: No I dont see the changes. Anyways I have edited my answer. The code is working just fine  provided ISDoneError turns out to be true. Judging from your screenshots i guess thats not the problem.